# Can't access files on Windows server via smb

Tags: debian, samba

I had been given access to a windows-based server using `samba` at my workplace. I use debian on my machine.

Using a file manager I can see the list of files and folders on the server. I can copy things to my machine, but I can not open any files on the server or copy things to the server. When I click on files or folders I get an error message "Failed to open directory XYZ. Connection timed out."

I have never worked with `samba`, so I have no idea what might be wrong.

I'd really appreciate any help.

Best wishes,

Jasmine

Answer (score 1):

I would try to connect via the command line because it might give you a better idea what and when it fails.

To check for basic connectivity problems, you could run:

```
nmblookup -B **theHostnameOfTheWindowsServer** __SAMBA__
```

This would check if the server is reachable via NETBIOS and if it announces a samba service. The output should include the IP of the Windows server.

With

```
smbclient -L **theHostnameOfTheWindowsServer** -U **yourUsername**
```

you should get a list of shares.

And

```
smbclient -U **yourUsername** '\\**theHostnameOfTheWindowsServer**\**nameOfShare**' # watch the backslashes
```

should connect you to the share and give you a shell like this:

```
smb: \>
```

Entering `l` should list files and directories (`?` for other commands)

Comment: Thank you Jonas for the quick reply and help! I managed to navigate to the folder of my interest. Yet when I try to list the files here, I get the following:    
'smb: \folder1\folder2> ls'     
 'NT_STATUS_IO_TIMEOUT listing \folder1\folder2*

Comment: We have a pretty slow server here where the initial listing can take around 10s but it's still working. Do people around you with Windows have slow file listings as well for that server?

Comment: Yes, it's pretty slow. It took me over 6 hours to copy 9GB data from the server to an external HDD, using a connected windows machine. Anyways, if this was the only issue I should still be able to open some small files, but I literally can not access anything from the server.

Comment: Sorry, I am out of ideas why you get so far but get a NT_STATUS_IO_TIMEOUT when trying to list files. You can set a higher timeout for `smbclient` with `-T` but I doubt this would change anything. Could it be that a firewall in front of the Windows Server drops some packets from your requests?